# How would I switch this from performing an AND operation to an OR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Right now this query searches a table called article for entries who's title and abstract field's contain a certain keyword. The set it returns are articles who's title AND abstract contain the keyword, but I would like to change it so it returns articles who's title OR abstract contains the keyword. How would I accomplish this? By simply changing the inner joins to an outer?

```
BEGIN
    with articlesearch as (
    SELECT top 1000 FT_TBL.articleID, FT_TBL.title,FT_TBL.abstract,FT_TBL.publicationdate,
        (select j.journalID from journal  j where FT_TBL.journalID=j.journalID) as sourceID,
        (select j.journalname from journal  j where FT_TBL.journalID=j.journalID) as sourcename,
        (select j2.medabbr from journal j2 where FT_TBL.journalID=j2.journalID) as medabbr,
        (select j1.impactfactor from journal  j1 where FT_TBL.journalID=j1.journalID) as impactfactor,
        KEY_TBL.RANK,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK desc) AS RowNumber
    FROM article AS FT_TBL 
        INNER JOIN 
            CONTAINSTABLE(article,title,@keyword) AS KEY_TBL
            ON FT_TBL.articleID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
        INNER JOIN
            CONTAINSTABLE(article,abstract,@keyword) AS KEY_TBL2
            ON FT_TBL.articleID = KEY_TBL2.[KEY]
    where  FT_TBL.inactive=0
    ORDER BY RANK DESC
    )

    SELECT articleID, sourcename,title,abstract,publicationdate,medabbr  
    FROM articlesearch
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @RowStart AND @RowEnd ORDER BY publicationdate desc;

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following version changes the `inner join`s to `left outer join`s and adds a `where` clause to get what you want:

```
with articlesearch as (
SELECT top 1000 FT_TBL.articleID, FT_TBL.title,FT_TBL.abstract,FT_TBL.publicationdate,
    (select j.journalID from journal  j where FT_TBL.journalID=j.journalID) as sourceID,
    (select j.journalname from journal  j where FT_TBL.journalID=j.journalID) as sourcename,
    (select j2.medabbr from journal j2 where FT_TBL.journalID=j2.journalID) as medabbr,
    (select j1.impactfactor from journal  j1 where FT_TBL.journalID=j1.journalID) as impactfactor,
    KEY_TBL.RANK,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK desc) AS RowNumber
FROM article AS FT_TBL 
    left outer JOIN 
        CONTAINSTABLE(article,title,@keyword) AS KEY_TBL
        ON FT_TBL.articleID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    left outer join 
        CONTAINSTABLE(article,abstract,@keyword) AS KEY_TBL2
        ON FT_TBL.articleID = KEY_TBL2.[KEY]
where FT_TBL.inactive=0 and (key_tbl.[key] is not null or key_tbl2.[key] is not null)
ORDER BY RANK DESC
)

SELECT articleID, sourcename,title,abstract,publicationdate,medabbr  
FROM articlesearch
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @RowStart AND @RowEnd ORDER BY publicationdate desc;
```

Comment: Is " left outer join JOIN" a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could change the `INNER JOIN` on each to a `LEFT JOIN` and that would get you what you want. Though I'll admit I'm not familiar with `CONTAINSTABLE`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the `INNER JOIN` to an `OUTER`, as DigitalD notes, but then you also need to filter your results where at least one of the joins isn't empty.

```
-- snip
----
-- /snip
FROM article AS FT_TBL 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        CONTAINSTABLE(article,title,@keyword) AS KEY_TBL
        ON FT_TBL.articleID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CONTAINSTABLE(article,abstract,@keyword) AS KEY_TBL2
        ON FT_TBL.articleID = KEY_TBL2.[KEY]
WHERE  FT_TBL.inactive=0
    AND (KEY_TBL.[KEY] IS NOT NULL OR KEY_TBL2.[KEY] IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY RANK DESC
)

-- snip
----
-- /snip
```